# Removing divs on page with attribute display:none via Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, prototype

There is a plug in that generates some divs on the page and when they are viewed it makes them display:none but all these pile up too much. How can I remove them via Javascript?

```
<div id="workarea">
<div id="message" class="messages" style="display: none;">Your message was saved</div>
<div id="message" class="messages" style="display: none;">Your message was saved</div>
<div id="message" class="messages" style="display: none;">Your message was saved</div>
<div id="message" class="messages" style="display: none;">Your message was saved</div>
</div>
```

Now I cant just do `$("workarea").innerHTML ="";` because there are more things i need in the work area at that point, also there are elements (other divs) that have `display:none` in the work area that i will want to keep. The best way would be something where i can grab the class like "messages" and make it find all the divs with `display:none` that have class "message" but how?

Comment: loop through the elements and see if they are hidden, if they are remove them using `removeChild`.

Comment: an id should be unique

Comment: @KooiInc Did you read the question? A plugin generates these...it doesn't seem they have control over that

Comment: If a plugin generates these, I would consider ditching the plugin.

Comment: @KooiInc I agree, but that doesn't seem to be the concern

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just loop through them and check `style.display` to see if it's `"none"`:

```
// Reminder to lurkers: This is Prototype, not jQuery!
$("workarea").childElements().each(function(child) {
    if (child.style.display === "none") {
        $(child).remove();
    }
});
```

Or if you want to restrict that to child elements of `#workarea` that have class `"messages"`:

```
// Reminder to lurkers: This is Prototype, not jQuery!
$("workarea").childElements().each(function(child) {
    if (child.style.display === "none" && child.hasClassName("messages")) {
        child.remove();
    }
});
```

Or for that matter:

```
// Reminder to lurkers: This is Prototype, not jQuery!
$$("#workarea > .messages").each(function(child) {
    if (child.style.display === "none") {
        $(child).remove();
    }
});
```

---

Side note: The HTML you've quoted is invalid. `id` values **must** be unique in the document, you can't have more than one `div` with the `id` `"message"`. Doesn't change the answer above, but I thought I should mention it. If those are being generated by a plug-in, I'd suggest using a different plug-in. :-)

Comment: nice answer.  As for the third method, is that correct to use 2 dollar signs in the beginning? thanks

Comment: @blachawk: Thanks! And yes: [`$$` in Prototype](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/dollar-dollar/) is basically `querySelectorAll` (or one of the several meanings of `$` in jQuery).

Answer (score 1):

You can find all the `id=message` elements and loop through them to see if their `display` style is set to "none":

```
var messageDivs = document.querySelectorAll('#workarea div[id="message"].messages');
for (var i = 0; i < messageDivs.length; i++) {
    var cur = messageDivs[i];
    if (cur.style.display === "none") {
        cur.parentNode.removeChild(cur);
    }
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/d8kzV/

References:

- `querySelectorAll`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll
- `removeChild`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.removeChild